Using .NET 8 Identity Endpoints Cookie to authorize another application
I am working on creating an identity microservice using the .NET Identity platform and the new Identity API endpoints. I have 3 separate applications that I am using for testing of the service: An identity api that validates user credentials and creates an authorization cookie, a client razor pages application that sends a post request to my Identity API and should receive the cookie to authenticate future requests, and a test API to serve as a dummy microservice. The Test API should be authenticated by the Identity API cookie.
Identity API Program.cs:
using IdentityService.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Security.Claims;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme)

    .AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDBContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDBContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityDatabase"));
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapIdentityApi<User>();

app.Run();

Client Web App PageModel Post Method for Login Call
  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
 {            
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
     {
         return Page();
     }
     LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest
     {
         Email = Request.Form["Email"],
         Password = Request.Form["Password"]
     };
     HttpClient client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("Auth");
     
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(new Uri(client.BaseAddress + "login?useCookies=true"), request);
     string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         
         return RedirectToPage("./Test");
     }
     return RedirectToPage("./Index");
 }

Test API Program.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder()
    .AddPolicy("api", p =>
    {
        p.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        p.AddAuthenticationSchemes(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
    });


builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\temp-keys")).SetApplicationName("IdentityService.API");
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapGet("api/foo", () =>
{
    return new[] { "One", "Two", "Three" };
})
    .RequireAuthorization("api");

app.Run();

Test API Controller Endpoint Im trying to hit from client app after being logged in:
namespace IdentityService.TestAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize("api")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<TestController> _logger;

        public TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Test API returned Successfully";
        }
    }
}

When I pass my login credentials to the client application and get a successful response, I don't get the cookie in my browser that I anticipate:

But I do get a cookie as expected if I log in using Swagger:

How can I get this cookie in my client application, and pass it to my test application to authenticate my endpoint?
I have looked at the documentation on sharing cookies across applications from Microsoft, but Im not sure which application needs the lines of code referenced. I've tried a few different combinations but none seems to work as expected.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Before fixing the issue, we need to know Cookie domain security first.
To put it simply, because cookies are segregated by domains, you're having the problem. Note: localhost:port1 and localhost:port2 are two domain names on the local machine.
Sharing cookies can only be done under the same domain name (first-level and second-level domains can also be shared).
Here is the official article about Sharing authentication cookies among ASP.NET apps.

cookies aren't segregated by port, though.  (CORS rules would do that, though, so I'm guessing there's a CORS error somewhere along the line here)
